# what does it mean of different eyepieces?

Tags: telescope

what is the difference between 4mm and 24mm and 30mm eyepieces?
could I buy an eyepiece from another brand?
I have the Gskyer telescope.could I buy for Celestron eyepieces?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The 4, 24 and 30mm eyepieces give different magnification (equal to the the focal length of the telescope in mm, divided by the number for the eyepiece).
You can use eyepieces from other brands, but make sure they have the same size barrel (the bit that slides into the telescope).  I don't know the Gskyer brand, but the eyepiece size will be either .965 inch or 1.25 inch.  Provided you get the same size, any other brand will work.  It's probably best to get familiar with what is provided by Gskyer before buying anything else.

You will likely find that using lower magnification at first gives the best outcome.

Comment: .965 inch size eyepieces are old and not often found anymore. Currently the most popular sizes are 1.25" and 2".

Comment: Well, some scopes still come with them.

Comment: so if it is going on increasing of mm.s will it give more magnification or less?

Comment: @Eng.Sultan : more mm (of focal length of eyepiece) means lower magnification, but wider area visible, and less obvious shake or wobble of whatever you are trying to see.

Comment: so if I want to see more deep for the moon and other planets should I buy less than 10mm because it's the smallest eyepiece I have.?

Comment: @Eng.Sultan, if you use the 10mm eyepiece with the barlow, that will give you about 100 magnification.  That is enough to see a lot of detail on the moon and probably the most your scope is capable of without giving a blurry image.